# Unable to apply API permissions to App Registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-application-settings

Attempting to apply API permissions to an App Registration results in the below error. Anyone have experience resolving this or do I need to wait on support from MS? I've cleared the cache, rebooted, tried incognito. I've had other GAs within our organization attempt as well, they get the same error.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue **"Network error: There is an issue establishing a connection to the service. Please refresh the browser to try again"** please try the below:

- Make sure you and your users have a ***subscription for Dynamic CRM.*** Users without the subscription may not be able to access of the features.
- Make sure your network has strict ***Security Policies***/ACLs.
- If you are trying from co-operate network and facing the issue then there might be some ***filtering configured on your network.***
- Try changing the network.
- Collect a ***network trace*** or browser trace to check if some requests are getting dropped.
- If the issue still persists, try to use the ***developer tools*** provided with the Edge Browser and see if you get any errors.
- Make sure you don't have any ***browser extensions*** enabled that could interfere with your traffic.

**I tested in my environment, and I am able to add the permissions.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure App Registration shows errors - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/274565/azure-app-registration-shows-errors.html)